# How do I use Microdata fields correctly?

Tags: html, microdata

The process of generating a list of events in a page a bit confusing to me.

In this example is the url supposed to represent the current page or a page you are referring to?

```
 <div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Person">
```

Would that be different from this example where I assume it literally does refer to the href?

```
 <a href="http://www.example.com" itemprop="url">www.example.com</a>
```

Can `itemprop="locality"` be used on zip codes or other postal codes?

Also, is there a way to specify you are referring to an Event and not a Person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely seem to have the right idea so far.  I have used [Schema.org](http://www.schema.org/) before, for setting up Microdata, and they supply an event property to hook into.

`<div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Event">`

Also, navigate to the [Event information page](http://www.schema.org/Event) to get a full readout of what properties it has.

It does have the option for a location with `itemprop="location"`.  You can see which Itemscopes you can use `location` on [here](http://www.schema.org/location).  One of the options is [PostalAddress](http://www.schema.org/PostalAddress) which has a some of examples which include using [postalCode](http://www.schema.org/postalCode) as a property.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
 <span itemprop="name">Google Inc.</span>
 P.O. Box<span itemprop="postOfficeBoxNumber">1234</span>
 <span itemprop="addressLocality">Mountain View</span>,
 <span itemprop="addressRegion">CA</span>
 <span itemprop="postalCode">94043</span>
 <span itemprop="addressCountry">United States</span>
</div>
```

There is also a full [tree-view](http://www.schema.org/docs/full.html) of all of the properties available to hook into.

Answer (score 1):

The value 'locality' refers to the city of a delivery address, so if you want to specify the postal code you can use the attribute postal-code:

```
<span itemprop="postal-code">99999</span>
```

Source: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html#names:-the-itemprop-attribute